# Unable to use react-native-image-picker on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I'm using react-native-image-picker to select and upload images on server. It works great on android, but throws error on iOS. The npm [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker) have provided a note that "On iOS, don't assume that the absolute uri returned will persist. See #107" what does it means? Will this library work on iOS? I'm trying with iOS simulator, it displays image properly but when I'm trying to upload on server using axios, it throws error "Missing request token for request: <NSURLRequest: 0x60000253e5a0> { URL: file://" like [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29364)
Is there any other alternative react-native library to upload images with iOS and android?

Comment: I used this one, https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

Comment: Thanks anthony willis muñoz for pointing this. After struggling for 16hrs, I found that react-native-image-picker & react-native-image-crop-picker both cannot be used on iOS simulators. It works perfectly fine on real devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a internal error. Try it.

Go to `node_modules/react-native/Image/RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.mm` and change this lines to:

```
 - (RCTImageLoaderCancellationBlock)loadImageForURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
                                           size:(CGSize)size
                                          scale:(CGFloat)scale
                                     resizeMode:(RCTResizeMode)resizeMode
                                progressHandler:(RCTImageLoaderProgressBlock)progressHandler
                             partialLoadHandler:(RCTImageLoaderPartialLoadBlock)partialLoadHandler
                              completionHandler:(RCTImageLoaderCompletionBlock)completionHandler
 {
   __block auto cancelled = std::make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);
   RCTExecuteOnMainQueue(^{
     if (cancelled->load()) {
       return;
     }

     UIImage *image = RCTImageFromLocalAssetURL(imageURL);
     if (image) {
       if (progressHandler) {
         progressHandler(1, 1);
       }
       completionHandler(nil, image);
     } else {
       NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not find image %@", imageURL];
       RCTLogWarn(@"%@", message);
       completionHandler(RCTErrorWithMessage(message), nil);
     }
   });

   return ^{
     cancelled->store(true);
   };
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Leonardo Leite. I have check that file, it seems the latest update has already made this change in package itself.

Comment: @Leonardo file not found on this location node_modules/react-native/Image/RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.mm

Comment: Hey @PunnetKansal try it in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.mm

Comment: should I replace all the code with this code?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to upload a file to a server, `react-native-image-picker` & `react-native-image-crop-picker` will not work on iOS simulators. It will throw:

> Missing request token for request: <NSURLRequest: 0x60000253e5a0> { URL: file://' error.

It works perfectly fine on real devices both android & ios. Just use a filename like this.

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: true,
  compressImageMaxHeight: 300,
  compressImageMaxWidth: 400,
  compressImageQuality: 0.5,
  mediaType: 'photo',
}).then(image => {
 
let filename = image.path.split('/').pop();
  
  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', {
    name: Platform.OS === 'android' ? filename : image.filename,
    type: image.mime,
    uri: image.path, 
  });
}
```